# Geometry of rational functions

Tags: geometry, soft-question, field-theory

Scott Carnahan writes at https://sbseminar.wordpress.com/2007/08/21/p-adic-fields-for-beginners/ that "One might ask if there are natural extensions of $\Omega_p$ that don’t add geometry (e.g., taking rational functions shouldn’t count).".

In what sense taking rational functions adds geometry to a field? For example, what is the difference between $\mathbb Q$ and $\mathbb Q(x)$ from the geometrical point of view?